# ¿Cómo subir un archivo almacenado en un directorio a mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy intentando subir un archivo que tengo almacenado en un directorio pero estoy teniendo un problema tengo la ruta concatenada con el nombre de la imagen y la extensión en la variable `$archivo_temporal` en el siguiente bloque de código:

```
    $data = array();
    $fp = fopen($archivo_temporal, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($archivo_temporal));
    $query = "
        CALL guardarFotoTrabajador(
            '{$flag}',
            '{$trabajador}',
            '{$persona}',
            '{$data}'
        );";
    echo $query;exit;
```

Pero al imprimir la ruta obtengo esta sentencia y no es posible ejecutarlo:

> ï»¿ CALL sp_nperTrabajadorQRCode( '1', 'T00000', '00000000', '‰PNG
> IHDR‘‘ùÈ`PLTEÿÿÿUÂÓ~ pHYsÄÄ•+ÛIDATH‰í”1„0QPæ ù <í"ñ1î'yeŠß:œw¢´% 
> 0)VY¯

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Tienes que conectar a PDO y mandar a ejecutar `$query`  con la instancia de PDO.

Comment: [Revisa el **Ejemplo 4** del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Te recomiendo que uses consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por las recomendaciones, termine cambiando mi sentencia a base de datos:

```
$query = "call guardarFotoTrabajador(:flag,:trabajador,:persona,:archivo);";

$parms = array(":flag" => 1,":trabajador" => 'T00000', ":persona" =>'00000000',":archivo"=>$contenido);
```

y ahora funciona, nuevamente gracias :) !